# What other tape manufacturers can I use in IBM LTO Gen 3 SAS Tape Drives

Tags: ibm, tape, lto

I have recently just got my hands on an IBM 3580S3V. I was just wondering if there are any other brands that I can use in this IBM gear?

LTO media are usually manufactured only by EMTEC, Imation, Fujifilm, Maxell, TDK and Sony (according to Wikipedia). I am trying to determine who OEM's the IBM tapes, or if possible, a list of media that IBM supports.

So far in my Google studies, I have only been able to see IBM as the supported media manufacturer (seeing as they sell tapes, I assume they don't want anyone buying media from competitors!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone's media will work so long as it's up to spec, but IBM will not support said media from  other manufacturers. They will support their drive using other's media, if you're under a support contract/warranty/etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any [LTO 3 Backup Tape](http://www.itdevicesonline.com/lto-3-tapes.php) in 3rd generation tape drive.